# Haskell Yesod stack build runnable file

Tags: haskell, docker, yesod, haskell-stack, keter

I was looking for ways to deploy my **Yesod** project, and while reading some tutorials (Keter and Docker way), I realised that, `stack build` generates a runnable file which can be executed directly and listen for requests, is there any reason I should not use it in production in the beginning? I think it would be great if it was that simple... I would run it in a Debian server hosted on Google Cloud.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work (assuming architectures are the same.)

Things to check:

1. Run `ldd` (`otool -L` on OS X) on the binary to see what shared libraries it references.
2. Make sure you've copied over any templates and data files.
3. Have a look at the section on **keter** in the Yesod book: http://www.yesodweb.com/book/deploying-your-webapp

The section on keter is valuable not only for info
on keter but also because it talks about the files you need to deploy
for a Yesod app.